# Temperature for Sphaleron Conversion Rate

Tags: cosmology, baryogenesis, leptogenesis

In Leptogenesis models, a Baryon asymmetry $B$ is obtained from the conversion of a $B-L$ (i.e. Baryon-Lepton number) via Sphaleron processes.
In the literature (i.e. [here](https://indico.fnal.gov/event/2341/contributions/72202/attachments/45209/54419/lg_nir.pdf)), the conversion rate $C_{sph}$ with which Sphalerons convert the $B-L$ to a $B$ asymmetry is often given as $C_{sph} = \frac{28}{79}$ if the conversion takes place before electroweak symmetry breaking and as $C_{sph} = \frac{12}{37}$ if it happens after.

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.3565v1.pdf), the critical Temperature $T_c$ where electroweak symmetry breaking takes places is given as around $T\sim 159$ GeV and the temperature where Sphalerons decouple is given as $T_*\sim 131$ GeV, i.e. Sphalerons decouple after symmetry breaking.

Say we have a high-scale Leptogenesis model where $B-L$ is generated at very high temperatures, i.e. $T\sim 10^8$ GeV. When choosing the conversion factor, what is the relevant temperature to determine $C_{sph}$? Are the Sphaleron processes so fast that the conversion happens only before symmetry breaking, i.e. $C_{sph} = \frac{28}{79}$, or is the temperature where Sphalerons decouple, $T_*$, the relevant one and therefore $C_{sph} = \frac{12}{37}$?

I am aware that the numerical difference between both factors is small but I am rather interested in understanding the general concept.